# Detect if iOS13 Dark Mode is enabled from Flutter/Dart

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ios-darkmode

I'm writing a Flutter app for Android and iOS which will change its style/theme based on iOS' Dark Mode status.

Is there currently anything like a MediaQuery.isDarkModeEnabled in Flutter?

There is a GitHub issue open [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33873) but the Flutter team must be overwhelmed in issues so I can't see this being implemented too soon.

I can use 'traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle' from iOS-specific code channels, but adding platform-specific code for Flutter/Dart apps is not something I'm experienced in. Currently working on this solution!

For example, someone could have a `CupertinoPicker` with adaptive colors:

```
CupertinoPicker(
    backgroundColor: isDarkModeEnabled ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
    children: items.map((thisItem) => Text(thisItem.name)).toList(),
    itemExtent: 32,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (newItem) {
        setState(() => this.item = items[newItem]);
    }
)
```

Comment: This is now on their 2019 milestone

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how you can set different colors for light and dark mode, the app will automatically switch if the phone is set to dark mode or light mode.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    // additional settings go here
  ),
);
```

::Update::

You can also get the platform brightness (Brightness.light / Brightness.dark) using

`WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness`

but you will have to use the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin and override the method below

```dart
@override
void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    print(WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness); // should print Brightness.light / Brightness.dark when you switch
    super.didChangePlatformBrightness(); // make sure you call this
}
```

see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html on how to use the mixin.

Comment: Does this work for iOS13 or only Android10?

Comment: I've not updated to Android 10, but it works on iOS13... perfectly!

Comment: Super sweet, I can confirm that this works for Android 10 ;)

Comment: It didn't work on iOS.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I just tried this on iOS, and darkTheme keeps returning as undefined.  So that's not an option.  Am I missing a dependancy?  Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What did you try, can we see? @ArthurEKing

Comment: I ended up having to do it manually, as there is no property darkTheme in either CupertinoApp or CupertinoThemeData.  So what I ended up doing was setting a bool  Brightness brightness = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context); bool isDark = brightness == Brightness.dark; and them creating the two manual ThemeData's dependant on the result of the bool.  It's not a streamlined, but it works.

Comment: so, yes, you're right, darkTheme property is not in CupertinoApp (at the moment)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible. Look here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33873#issuecomment-536309491
and here is the answer.

```
if(ios13==true){
    bool qDarkmodeEnable;
    var qdarkMode = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    if (qdarkMode == Brightness.dark){
        qDarkmodeEnable=true;
    } else {
        qDarkmodeEnable=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the iOS 13 variable...where would it go in the project?

Comment: I use sharedPreferences and deviceInfo libs with devices info obtain the version of iOS or Android and return true if the iOS version is 13.0 and save the value on sharedPreferences. I hope that may be help you