# Platform brightness is still light on iOS even when dark mode is on - Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-darkmode

I am trying to implement dark mode in my flutter app, but I don't know what am I missing but it doesn't work on iOS. I manage to run it on Android just fine, but when I print `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness` there is still light, event when dark mode is on.

When I set themeMode: ThemeMode.dark - dark mode is working, problem is with the automatic detection.

Also, when I run new blank project, dark mode worked fine. But in my app, which is builded, it does not work. Even if `themeMode` is set to `ThemeMode.system`:

```dart
      themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      theme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: darkBlue,
        cursorColor: red,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        accentColor: Colors.white,
        cursorColor: red,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
```

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong or do you have any suggestions?

Flutter version: **1.12.13-hotfix.9** and
iOS version: **iPhone SE simulator - iOS 13.3**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475630/detect-if-ios13-dark-mode-is-enabled-from-flutter-dart?

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach Yes, I tried this solution, but does not work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figure it out - just simply removed this entry from `info.plist` that I have added before.

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Comment: For those who are wondering: this also prevents `WidgetsBindingObserver.didChangePlatformBrightness()` from being called, because the `UIUserInterfaceStyle` is always `Light` and never changing. Thx!!