# how to get notified whenever the user changes the os theme in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, stream, provider

I am trying to get notified, whenever the user changes the theme of the operating system. I want to use Provider to accomplish that, however dart Provider needs a Stream that gives a Snapshot, whenerver somthing is changed or getsupdated. So I need to emplement or rather use a Stream, that gives me a snapshot whenever the os theme gets changed.

Here is my code. It is nothing special. But I really want to know how to get this Provider up and running with a Stream

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(initialRoute: '/', routes: {
      '/': (context) => MainPage(),
    }));
```

This class is a wrapper for the HomePage. It contains the Provider.
(value: brightnessStream) is a dummy value, and that is what I need to implement.

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Brightness>.value(
      initialData: Brightness.light,
      value: brightnessStream,
      child: Home(), 
    );
  }
}
```

In this class I am listening to the Stream, whenever the brightness changes and displying a text that shows the current theme.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final brightness = Provider.of<Brightness>(context); 
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(brightness.toString()),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

the stream should like somethig like this.

```
Stream<Brightness> get brightnessStream {
  // return stream of os brigtness (os theme)
}
```

So how is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you can set different colors for light and dark mode, the app will automatically switch if the phone is set to dark mode or light mode.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    // additional settings go here
  ),
);
```

You can also get the platform brightness (Brightness.light / Brightness.dark) using

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness
```

but you will have to use the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin and override the method below

```
@override
void didChangePlatformBrightness() {
    print(WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness); // should print Brightness.light / Brightness.dark when you switch
    super.didChangePlatformBrightness(); // make sure you call this
}
```

and then inside the `didChangePlatformBrightness` you can add to your stream.

This is also duplicate.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58227507/14818033) to view

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. I solved the Problem like this:

```
class Theme {
  final window = WidgetsBinding.instance.window;
  final _controller = StreamController<Brightness>();

  Theme() {
    window.onPlatformBrightnessChanged = () {
      // This callback gets invoked every time brightness changes
      final brightness = window.platformBrightness;
      _controller.sink.add(brightness);
    };
  }

  Stream<Brightness> get stream => _controller.stream;
}
```

so I built my own stream